# Knockout: extend computed to deal with different observables

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout computed that works similarly to a check/uncheck all but on strings for 'yes' and 'no' radio buttons.

I'd like to try and extend this so that it will work against a different observable property. At the moment, if all 'paramOne' properties from the 'optionList' are selected as 'yes' then I return 'yes', similarly for 'no'. But I'd like to use it also for the 'paramTwo' parameter and 'paramThree' parameter etc.

Any ideas how to do this? Maybe a computed is not the best fit here?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3kpx5qaf/

```
var AppViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

  self.optionList = ko.observableArray();
  self.optionList().push({
    id : 'option1',
    title: "option one",
    paramOne:ko.observable(),
    paramTwo: ko.observable(),
    paramThree: ko.observable(),
    paramFour: ko.observable()
  });
  self.optionList().push({
    id : 'option2',
    title: "option two",
    paramOne:ko.observable(),
    paramTwo: ko.observable(),
    paramThree: ko.observable(),
    paramFour: ko.observable()
  });


  self.selectAll = ko.computed({
      read: function() {

      var numNo = 0;
      var numYes = 0;
      var items = self.optionList();

      ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function(item) {
          if(item.paramOne() == "No"){
              numNo += 1;
          }else if(item.paramOne() == "Yes"){
              numYes += 1;
          }
      });

      if(numNo == items.length){
          return "No";
      }else if(numYes == items.length){
          return "Yes";
      }else{
          return null;
      }
  },
  write: function(value) {

      var items = self.optionList();

      ko.utils.arrayForEach(items, function(item) {
          item.paramOne(value);
      });
      }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: What's the point of having `"yes"` and `"no"` instead of `true` and `false`? Using two strings to represent Boolean values is cumbersome, error-prone, has internationalization issues and all that while offering no functional benefits. So why do it?

Comment: Agree, a boolean would be a better fit here but the example from the knockout documentation is based on the radio button value (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) so that was the first thing I did.

Comment: I agree with Jeroen about the XY-problem. Instead of describing the solution you want to implement, describe the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very likely have an XY-problem. You even allude to this yourself by asking "*is X not the best fit here?*". However, you have not given any context or *real* examples (I hope your real code doesn't have "`ParamOne`" etc as variables?). So it's pretty hard to suggest a better solution.

The question you're asking about the approach you currently have, can be paraphrased as:

> How can I DRY up the `computed` functions so they can be reused for `paramTwo` etc?

You can simply do *that* by extracting that bit of code. Here's one simple example with just javascript:

```
var AppViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  // ...code omitted for brevity...

  function getReadFn(propertyName) {
    return function() {

      var numNo = 0;
      var numYes = 0;
      var items = self.optionList();

      ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function(item) {
        if (item[propertyName]() == "No") { numNo += 1; }
        else if (item[propertyName]() == "Yes") { numYes += 1; }
      });

      if (numNo == items.length) { return "No"; }
      else if (numYes == items.length) { return "Yes"; }
      else { return null; }
    };
  }

  function getWriteFn(propertyName) {
    return function(value) {
      var items = self.optionList();

      ko.utils.arrayForEach(items, function(item) {
          item[propertyName](value);
      });
    };
  }

  self.selectAll_paramOne = ko.computed({
    read: getReadFn("paramOne"),
    write: getWriteFn("paramOne")
  });

  self.selectAll_paramTwo = ko.computed({
    read: getReadFn("paramTwo"),
    write: getWriteFn("paramTwo")
  });

  //etc.
}
```

Alternatively, you could also [create your own extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) to encapsulate the logic.

However, again, please evaluate your approach carefully. Specifically:

- Is "yes" / "no" not really a localization issue, and shouldn't your backing observables be booleans?
- Should your `paramOne`/etc observables not actually be an (observable) list or plain arry?
- Can't you heavily simplify your functions by utilizing array functions like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)? (this depends a bit on browsers you need to support / polyfills you could use)

Comment: Agree about the booleans (see my comment above). Also I gave the the properties basic names (paramOne) just because my real-world example would require a bit more explanation - though it was easier this way. It would be ok for the observables to be plain properties rather than observables since they are only affected by the UI. I need to support IE8 so although simplifying the array functions may be possible, I've not looked at this yet.

Comment: In that case I stand by my answer :-)

Comment: @user2424495 To support IE8 I suggest including the Sugar.js library, which does not only fill in the missing array methods but also adds quite a lot of other very useful utilities.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I gather you want a property that becomes `"yes"` or `"no"` if all parameters of an option are equally `"yes"` or `"no"` - or `null` if there's a mismatch.

For lack of a better name, let's call that property `overallSelection`. Since its value depends on a bunch of observables, it's natural to use a ko.computed to do the job.

Your sample application consists of two parts - an `Option`, which has several params, and an `OptionList`, i.e. a container for options. So that's two viewmodels, implemented as below (run the code by clicking the button beneath):

```js
function Option(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.paramNames = ["paramOne", "paramTwo", "paramThree", "paramFour"];
    self.id = data.id;
    self.title = data.title;
    self.paramNames.forEach(function (paramName) {
        self[paramName] = ko.observable();
    });

    self.overallSelection = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var ref;
        self.paramNames.forEach(function (paramName, i) {
            if (i === 0) ref = self[paramName]();
            else if (ref !== self[paramName]()) ref = null;
        });
        return ref;
    });
}
function OptionList(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.options = ko.observableArray(data.options.map(function (data) {
        return new Option(data);
    }));
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
var vm = new OptionList({
    options: [
        {id: 'option1', title: 'option one'},
        {id: 'option2', title: 'option two'}
    ]
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.param {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: options">
  <li>
    <h4 data-bind="text: title"></h4>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: paramNames">
      <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data" class="param"></span>
        <label><input type="radio" value="yes" data-bind="checked: $parent[$data]"> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" value="no" data-bind="checked: $parent[$data]"> No</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <b class="param">Overall</b> <span data-bind="text: overallSelection"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Notes:

- Currently this uses `"yes"` or `"no"`, but as indicated in the comments I would dis-recommend that variant. It's easy to change to actual Boolean values by switching from `value` attributes to the `checkedValue` binding (part of [the docs on the `checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)).
- My `overallSelection` computed returns any value as long as all involved parameters share it. No code changes are necessary if you switch to Boolean.
- The whole thing is designed in such a way that data is passed down into the viewmodel constructor. It's useful to design viewmodels in such a way, it increases their flexibility.
- This uses the array prototype functions available in modern browsers. To support old and new browsers alike, either switch to the equivalents from `ko.utils` or use polyfills (I tend to recommend [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/)).
- General tip: Naming is hard. Try not to give names like `selectAll` to things that do not, actually, "select all".